# How to use a For loop to create new variables in a 3X450

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to set up a code to analyze some data and I'm rather new to R and not an experienced coder.  I have created a 3 column 450ish row variable, every 14 rows it becomes a new condition. I wanted to create a for loop that would take 1:14 row and create a new named variable for it.  I then need to check for a response in there, although thats not part of this.  Sorry if this seems simple!  The first column of the variable is changing name that I would have associated with it, ie columns read name, trial #, then response.

I've tried creating a list and then associating it out with no luck.

Ideally, I would end up with 32 new variables that are all 3x14 that I could then feed into something else.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're asking without a replicable data-set. Here's a small example instead on two trials with 5 test each kept in the long-format:

```
set.seed(4)
test <- data.frame(test = rep(letters[1:5], 2), test_value = sample(1:100, 10, replace=TRUE))
test
```

> ```
>    test test_value
> 1     a         76
> 2     b         29
> 3     c         11
> 4     d         96
> 5     e         42
> 6     a         46
> 7     b         98
> 8     c         59
> 9     d         97
> 10    e         77
> ```

```
## create new indicator variable for each trial of 5 tests in this case

test$trial <- unlist(lapply(c("trial_1", "trial_2"), function(x) rep(x, 5)))
test
```

> ```
>    test test_value   trial
> 1     a         76 trial_1
> 2     b         29 trial_1
> 3     c         11 trial_1
> 4     d         96 trial_1
> 5     e         42 trial_1
> 6     a         46 trial_2
> 7     b         98 trial_2
> 8     c         59 trial_2
> 9     d         97 trial_2
> 10    e         77 trial_2
> ```

## spread data so that each trial has 5 test, each with a value ##

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)

test %>% group_by(trial) %>% spread(test, test_value)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 6
> # Groups:   trial [2]
>      trial       a     b     c     d     e
>      <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
>   1 trial_1    76    29    11    96    42
>   2 trial_2    46    98    59    97    77
> ```

Hope this is helpful.